# Change the Synergy notification icon?

Tags: indicator, notification, icons, synergy

I use [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) to sync mouse and keyboard between desktops.

**My question is, how do I change the Synergy indicator icons in Unity?**

For reference, I am using the [Faenza](http://tiheum.deviantart.com/art/Faenza-Icons-173323228) icon theme, and this is what my indicator bar looks like in Unity:
[current unity panel http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17323455/images/synergy-icon/old-panel.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17323455/images/synergy-icon/old-panel.png)

I have made Faenza styled replacements for the **three icon states** of Synergy.
[disconnected icon http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17323455/images/synergy-icon/synergy-disconnected.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17323455/images/synergy-icon/synergy-disconnected.svg)
[connected icon http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17323455/images/synergy-icon/synergy-connected.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17323455/images/synergy-icon/synergy-connected.svg)
[warning icon http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17323455/images/synergy-icon/warning.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17323455/images/synergy-icon/warning.svg)
Connected example:
[proposed unity panel http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17323455/images/synergy-icon/new-panel.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17323455/images/synergy-icon/new-panel.png)

**I have tried**:

- Naming the icons `synergy-connected`, `synergy-disconnected` and `warning` respectively. I got these names from the icons used in [Synergy's source files](http://synergy-foss.org/download/)
- Resizing icons (to 16, 22, 24 and 32) and placing them in `/usr/share/icons/Faenza/status/XX`

  - *replace* `XX` *with icon resolution*
- Placing the svg's in `/usr/share/icons/Faenza/scalable`
- The above two points, but instead in the `Faenza Dark` folder
- Add the svg's in `~/.icons`

**Thoughts**:
I have thought of adding the custom icons to the source, compiling said source and installing... But that would defeat the purpose of icon themes and in the future I would want to use different icons with different icon themes without the hassle of compiling source each time; I don't think it is within the scope of this problem to consider compiling from source with custom icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synergy includes their icons when compiling the executables and does not fully support [app indicators in Ubuntu](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/) for chosen icon themes.

A [feature request](http://synergy-foss.org/tracker/issues/3272) on Synergy tracker website for indicator support has been created and should be viewed/upvoted when considering this problem.